# load dataset into rdd from website in spark

Tags: python, pyspark, dataset

I load dataset with tar.gz file from website in pyspark. 
`dataset=spark.sparkContext.textFile('https://www.example/example.tar.gz')` (the url is just an example)
and 
`dataset.collect()`
get error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot load files directly into  core spark from website. You have to download files from website to your local file system and load it as follows

```
dataset=spark.sparkContext.textFile("file:///your file local file path")
```

or after placing files in hdfs using

```
dataset=spark.sparkContext.textFile(" your hdfs file path")
```